# What is the iPhone's "Springboard" view exactly?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, ios-universal-app, springboard

My question is, is the default iPhone menu a UIcollection view created with storyboarding, or is there more to its abilities? (in order to avoid emulating its functionality)

Comment: If this is going to be submitted to the App Store (rather than enterprise distribution), creating a "wrapper app" of widgets or attempting to emulate anything like the iOS icon grid violates the submission guidelines.

Comment: Since the Springboard was already part of the first version of iPhone OS, and `UICollectionView` is new since iOS6 it's very unlikely Springboard is an `UICollectionView`. However, if you want to make a similiar layout: that would be perfectly possible using an `UICollectionView`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to understand SpringBoard's view hierarchy:

1. Launch the iOS Simulator if it's not already running.
2. Make sure you're looking at SpringBoard in the simulator.
3. In Xcode, choose Product > Attach to Process > springboard.  The springboard process is way down in the “System” section of the list.
4. Still in Xcode, choose Product > Debug > Pause.
5. In Xcode's debug console (where it should show the `(lldb)` prompt), type `po [[UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]`.

Voila, you get a printout of SpringBoard's entire on-screen view hierarchy.  Mine starts out like this:

```
(lldb) po [[UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
$0 = 0x0b63abf0 <SBAppWindow: 0xce3ef10; baseClass = UIWindow; frame = (0 0; 320 480); layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0xce3f010>>
   | <SBUIRootView: 0xb162de0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); layer = <CALayer: 0xb162e60>>
   |    | <UIView: 0xb163010; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xb1630c0>>
   |    |    | <SBWallpaperView: 0xb1632a0; baseClass = UIImageView; frame = (0 0; 320 480); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xb160f70>>
   |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xb1610d0; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xb161130>>
   |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0xb161160; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xb163390>>
   |    |    | <SBIconContentView: 0xb163da0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xb163e50>>
   |    |    |    | <UIView: 0xc939710; frame = (0 371; 320 109); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+TM; layer = <CALayer: 0xc939770>>
   |    |    |    |    | <SBDockIconListView: 0xc9381d0; frame = (0 20; 320 89); autoresize = TM; layer = <CALayer: 0xc9382c0>>
...
```

Comment: Does this still work in 2018? It shows an error message "Ensure “SpringBoard” is not already running, and `username` has permission to debug it."

Comment: I'm able to do it with Xcode 10.1 on macOS 10.13.6, but I have a non-standard SIP configuration. Specifically, I booted my recovery partition, opened Terminal, and ran `csrutil enable --without debugging --without dtrace`. That means I can use the debugger and dtrace to analyze system processes.

Comment: I tried `~ lldb -n SpringBoard` on my MBP running macOS 10.14, that showed an error message `attach failed: unable to attach`. When I switched to my another MBP running 10.13.6, it ran successfully. Do you recommend running `csrutil enable --without debug --without dtrace` on my personal 10.14 MB without booting from a recovery partition? Or maybe you have an explanation why it's not working on 10.14..

Comment: I don't have a Mac running 10.14 to experiment on. You must boot your recovery partition to modify your SIP configuration (using `csrutil`). The changes then take effect when you reboot back in your normal partition.

Answer (score 1):

From Wikipedia article on [Springboard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpringBoard):

**Springboard**, or **Home Screen** is the standard application that manages the iOS home screen. Other tasks include starting WindowServer, launching and bootstrapping applications and setting some of the device's settings on startup.

Comment: Nice n concise. Thank you, Black Frog.